# My Terminal Console not working in Visual Studio Code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, terminal, console

When I open my terminal console, it is disappearing with a pop-up message as shown below:

> The terminal process "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" terminated with exit code: 4294901760.

Comment: This can be caused by an extension. Try to disable all extensions restart VS Code and try again

Comment: Or check if you mistakenly set [wrong terminal args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63598786/vscode-terminal-launch-error-with-exit-code-4294770688#comment112465140_63598786)